# cp command with Key for each file

Tags: amazon-s3, aws-cli

I have a folder structure like

- Test
- Test2

  2. Test2-1.jpg
  3. Test2-2.png

Using `cp` command I am able to copy the local structure to the S3 bucket. But I have a server configured to access files like this in a bucket

`Test2/Test2-1.jpg`, because I have copied it using cp command from a local directory, I can't set the key to `Test2/Test2-1.jpg`.

Before I was copying each and every file manually through Boto API by setting Key manually. That worked but its very long process.

Is there any way I can achieve this using cp command?

**EDIT:**

The actual issue causing the problem was content-encoding gzip. I was passing this encoding for not `gz` file. Due to that, the file is not stored properly and accessible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are in a directory with `Test2-1.jpg` in it you can copy it to `yourbucket/Test2/Test2-1.jpg` by running

```
  aws s3 cp ./Test2-1.jpg s3://yourbucket/Test2/Test2-1.jpg
```

You can copy an entire directory by using the sync command

```
  aws s3 sync . s3://yourbucket/Test2/
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. But I am not copying file by file. I am copying from the root directory.

Comment: I am able to copy the entire directory. I am having trouble accessing the file using folder path like in my question.